# How to generate the USER_AGENT for AdWords API script

Tags: google-oauth, google-ads-api

What is the most effective way to generate the USER_AGENT in order to pull data from the AdWords-API using Python? This value is the last value I need to be able to pull data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
user_agent: INSERT_USER_AGENT_HERE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thankfully, I figured out how to resolve this. As noted here:

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2013/11/please-set-user-agent-or-application.html

the USER_AGENT field is an optional field. The AdWords, DFP, and DFA APIs can take a user agent string in the SOAP headers, and the client libraries all allow you to set this string in their configuration files. That said, it is in your own best interests to set this value to something unique and useful for each of your applications.